# Equation of a line given point, perpendicular line and intersecting line

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, euclidean-geometry

My problem states:

> Find the equation of the line ***$r$*** knowing that:
>
> $r$ passes through the point B = (-1, 2, -3)
>
> $r$ is perpendicular to the line $s$ = (-1+6λ, -3-2λ, 2-3λ)
>
> $r$ intersects with the line $s'$ = (-1+3λ, -1+2λ, 3-5λ)

So if $r$ is in a plane perpendicular to the line $s$, I can use the direction vector of $s$ as the normal vector of that plane. I could also find the point A where $s$ intersects that plane, and if I take B to be contained in the plane as well, I can find $r$ with A and B.

However, I'm not at all sure if this idea is correct, and furthermore, I don't know if it's an appropriate method at all because I have no idea how to relate it to the third idea of $r$ intersecting $s'$... thus I have arrived at SE to ask for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’s not quite correct, but the question could’ve been worded better. The second criterion isn’t meant to imply that $r$ and $s$ intersect; only that their direction vectors are perpendicular. So $r$ does lie in the plane through $B$ perpendicular to $s$, but you still need a second point for $r$. That’s where $s'$ comes in: the point where it intersects this plane will give you a second point for $r$.

There’s another, equivalent, way to use $s'$: since $r$ and $s'$ intersect, they must be coplanar, so $r$ also lies in the plane defined by $s'$ and $B$, and is in fact the intersection of the two planes. This allows you to compute the direction vector of $r$ without solving any equations: $r$ is perpendicular to the normals of both planes, so their cross product is parallel to the line. The direction vector of $s$ is normal to the first plane, as you’ve already noted, and a normal to the second can be obtained via another cross product: $(3,2,-5)\times(B-(-1,-1,3))$

Comment: Hi amd, thanks for your help. I've reached the conclusion that the plane I'm constructing has the general equation $6x-2y-3z-1=0$. I'm now substituting the equation for $s'$ into the equation of the plane, but the values I'm getting for λ are suspiciously ugly. I'm reaching the conclusion that λ = 12/29 when I substitute the variables in the equation of my plane with -1+3λ, -1+2λ, 3-5λ.

Comment: @JakeS, There is a slightly different way to do it.  Let $ \vec d_r = \vec {s'} (λ) - B $ be the direction vector of line **r** and $ \vec n $ be the direction vector of the perpendiclar line (also the normal to the plane).  When $ \vec d_r \cdot \vec n = 0 $ the two are perpendicular.  I also get $ λ = 12/29 $.  Carry on.  Who says all answers have to be "neat"?

Comment: @JakeS You’ve got a sign error in the plane equation in your comment. That aside, $12/29$ doesn’t look all that ugly to me.

Comment: Much thanks to both of you. I end up reaching the parametrized equation of $r$ to be (-1 + λ(-36/29), 2 + λ(63/29), -3 + λ(-114/29)). I substituted into the equation of $s'$, used the point I found along with $B$ to find the direction vector of $r$, and constructed my equation for $r$. Much thanks to you both!

Comment: @JakeS See my recent update for a way to compute the direction vector directly, without solving any equations.

Answer (score 1):

Since you know how to figure out the plane that is perpendicular to line **S**, which contains point **B**, you are most of the way there.

Observe that line **s'** is not perpendicular to line **S** which means it must intersect the plane somewhere.  Find that point and you have the second point for your line.

Hope this helps, but not too much.

Ced

---

Followup:

$$ \vec d_r =  (-1+3\lambda, -1+2\lambda, 3-5\lambda) -  (-1, 2, -3) = (0, -3, 6) + (3,2,-5)\lambda $$

$$ \vec n = ( 6, -2, -3 ) $$

$$ \vec d_r \cdot \vec n = 0 $$

$$ -12 + 29 \lambda = 0 $$

$$ \lambda = \frac{12}{29} $$

Comment: Thanks for your help Ced! See my comment on amd's answer for how I've progressed and how I'm stuck, haha.

Comment: @JakeS. See my followup.